# Using Tableau to do VLookup

Tags: lookup, tableau-api, formulas

New to Tableau so sorry if this is obvious, but I had a hunt and couldn't find/understand anything.  So I have a cake shop and I want to know if people have purchased both éclairs and Eccles cakes in the same order

```
ORDER ID     item 
0001         éclair
0001         iced bun
0001         Eccles cake
0002         éclair 
0002         iced bun
0003         éclair          
0003         Eccles cake
```

What I want as an output is the following:

```
ORDER ID     item          éclair?
0001         éclair          0
0001         iced bun        0
0001         Eccles cake     1
0002         éclair          0
0002         iced bun        0
0003         éclair          0
0003         Eccles cake     1
```

I'm thinking it requires something like a lookup, or a helper column?!

For reference, I've got a single data set (a csv file) so I'm guessing I can't run a SQL query on it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I was able to do this - there may be a better way that I am not familiar with. Nonetheless...

---

**Steps:**

1. In a sheet, add `Order Id` and `Item` to the `Rows` section.
2. Duplicate your data source (right click > Duplicate). I'll refer to the original as `A` and the copy as `B`.
3. Unlink the `Item` field. This is done by clicking the orange chain link icon to the right of the field name. A gray link is what you want. Leave the `Order Id` field linked (orange).
4. Staying on the same sheet, click on data source `B` and create these two calculated fields:
   Cake_Flag:  `MAX(IF [Item] = 'Eccles cake' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

   Eclair_Flag:   `MAX(IF [Item] = 'éclair' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`
5. Return to data source `A` by selecting it and create this new calculated field:
   éclair?:   `IF ATTR([Item]) = 'Eccles cake' AND [Data Source B].[Eclair Flag] = 1 AND [Data Source B].[Cake Flag] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

   `[Data Source B]` should be replaced with whatever the name of your `B` data source is.
6. Place the new calculated field `éclair?` in the Text card.

---

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I would not recommend using data blending for this. It's not necessary, and you now are using two database queries instead of one, and spending time to combine the query results on the client side. Adds complexity and performance costs. Not a problem for small datasets, but is for larger ones.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using data blending for this. It provides the proper solution. You have not proposed a working alternate solution, so I'm not sure what you can really say about this.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with data blending on small data sets. It can really bite you with large ones (especially if your linking fields are at a fine level of granularity)

Answer (score -1):

See [Set difference: find distinct members for two groups in Tableau Desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527332/set-difference-find-distinct-members-for-two-groups-in-tableau-desktop) for a start one of several possible approaches. The crux is writing an aggregated calculated field that calculates whether an order id contains both items of interest.

You can use that calculation in a set or directly in a view where order id is a dimension.

An example would be:

```
count(if item = "eclair" then 1 end) > 0 and count(if item = "Eccles cake" then 1 end) > 0
```

This (aggregated) calculation returns true for orders that have at least one eclair item and at least one Eccles cake item, false for other orders.

For this to work, you need Order ID as a dimension in your view, but not item, so that the calculation is applied to all the items in an order at one time. That answers the question you posed, but displays one row per order instead of one row per order/item.

If you really need the exact output form you specified, then you turn this calculation into an LOD calc, such as:

```
{ FIXED [ORDER ID] : count(if item = "eclair" then 1 end) > 0 and count(if item = "Eccles cake" > 0 then 1 end) }
```

Then you display a column next to each order id/item to indicate whether or not the order contained both an eclair and a cake. (Which is also not exactly what you show as desired output) or use this new field along with the the current item to define a final calculation that is 1 if and only if the item is cake and the order contains both.

This evaluates to true and false. I presume you can convert to 1 and 0 if needed.

Comment: That won't work considering OP's desired output. Tableau will only evaluate the current record/partition, not the pane.

Comment: It would answer the question he asked "wanting to know if people purchased both products in the same order" -- but this calculation assumes that order ID is the finest grained dimension on the sheet -- so your right that the output isn't exactly as they requested. If that is significant to the problem, they can wrap the above calculation as an LOD calc. I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: The LOB calc is an interesting approach; however, did you test this also? First there is a small error in the calc. Second it does not return the output the OP is looking for because it would return TRUE or FALSE for every record within the same `Order ID`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the cut and paste error in the second calc. I fixed. Surely,  the question is about distinguishing orders that meet conditions, not about whether to print 1 or true.

Comment: It wasnt about 1 vs TRUE - Your solution produces the same result (whether 1, 0, TRUE, FALSE) for every record within the same `Order ID`, which is not what was requested. I ran your solution as a test - this is how I know. Are you testing the solutions that you are proposing?

Comment: I understand that the approach I showed does not print out the information in the same format he requested. But, more importantly, it does show the efficient and simple way to answer his more general question -- i.e. how to distinguish orders that satisfy some condition involving their subordinate items. That's a very common question, and I showed the standard solution. I don't think the rest is critical, but you can use aliases to display true as 1 if he wants, and can use an LOD calc if he really wants put a 1 by some but not all the items in an order. No need to argue about it.

Comment: @AlexBlakemore Please could you use none gendered pronouns, or the widely used "OP" rather than assuming I'm a male. It marginalises the female community on here (which is at a minority).

Comment: @Datahoe Sorry for the gender assumption. I'll choose pronouns more carefully in the future. All the other discussion aside, have you solved your original problem?